# Creating Custom broadcast (udp) traffic in Opnet

Tags: networking, simulation, opnet

I'm modelling a network on Opnets(14.5) on network Editör. I have Broadcast traffic to simulate (via UDP) :

The explict traffic can be created with Task-,Application- and Profile Configuration nodes. I'm traying it but there is no area to write a Broadcast (IP) address. İt is workin on Symbolic names and I dont found a Synbolic name for Broadcast.

I'm open to another suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an application, a task so on, using the IP flow model. You can set it as Broadcast traffic.